# How to align a bulleted list with other text on same line - Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

Bullet   List Item   Other text
Bullet   List Item   Other text
Bullet   List Item   Other text

I have the following so far, however I'm getting an overlap effect. Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
<ul>
   <li class='pull-left'>Price #1:</li><span class='pricing-reservations-large-price'>$100</span>
   <li class='pull-left'>Price #2:</li><span class='pricing-reservations-large-price'>$200</span>
</ul>

.pricing-reservations-large-price {
   display:block;
    padding: 1.5%;
    width:auto;
    float: left;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:10%;
    -moz-border-radius:10%;
    -webkit-border-radius:10%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10%;
    background:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #870820;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. you cannot put spans in a UL. Did you mean to put them **inside** the `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't have anything directly in a `ul` that isn't an `li`. Best to put the `span` inside the `li`. Also, I don't think `.pull-left` is needed at all:

```
<ul>
   <li>Price #1:<span class='pricing-reservations-large-price'>$100</span></li>
   <li>Price #2:<span class='pricing-reservations-large-price'>$200</span></li>
</ul>
```

Unless you really need old IE support, you want `display: inline-block;` too:

```
.pricing-reservations-large-price {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 1.5%;
    -moz-border-radius:10%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10%;
    -webkit-border-radius:10%;
    border-radius:10%;
    background:#eee;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #870820;
}
```

P.S.: `width: auto`, `height: auto`, and `text-align: center` aren't really doing much here, and `border-radius` should always come *after* the extension versions.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RYsbT/1/

Answer (score 0):

## [Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/BR5H6/)

Try changing your CSS to:

```
.pricing-reservations-large-price {
    padding: 1.5%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:10%;
    -moz-border-radius:10%;
    -webkit-border-radius:10%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10%;
    background:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #870820;
}
```

And your HTML to:

```
<ul>
   <li class='pull-left'>Price #1:<span class='pricing-reservations-large-price'>$100</span></li>
   <li class='pull-left'>Price #2:<span class='pricing-reservations-large-price'>$200</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.pricing-reservations-large-price {
    padding: 1.5%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:10%;
    background:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #870820;
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

## [Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VLKdM/1/)